# Cannot switch between multiple Google Docs accounts being signed in them correctly

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-account

Here https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2405894 I read I can sign in multiple Google accounts and easily switch between them in Google Docs app. But it is not true. It doesn't work. I'm talking about desk top version now, not mobile.

I can sign in more than one account but I cannot switch between them. Google forces me to sign out current account to be able to sign in other one.

Here is a screenshot I'm really signed in three accounts:
[image]

And instead of just switching me other account I'm asked to sign out current first:

[image]

How to enable mechanic explained in docs? Or is it explained in docs only but not available in real life?

Comment: Please note that the first two options include a link with the text "Why?". Follow that link and update your question.

Comment: The "Why?" link is totally useless. It tells you nothing about _why_ you can't change. Or, it tells you one reason, but not all the reasons. Specifically not the reason for me.


_"You can add and switch between multiple Google accounts on Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides. To switch accounts on Google Drive, disconnect and reinstall with your other account.

Note: You cannot switch between two @gmail.com accounts."_

Answer (score 1):

In the docs [link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2405894) you specified the first line says "You can’t switch between accounts that end in @gmail.com in Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides"

[image]

Comment: Yeah..., BUT WHY would you (i. e. Google) put in such a constraint!?